# trying to run an execsync on a command but keeps getting ... is not recognized as an internal

Tags: node.js, child-process

i am trying to run a postgresql dump from execsync command but I keep getting the following error:

```
Command failed: pg_dump --no-owner --file=d:\\Dev\\...\\..\\..\\...\\...bak postgres://Username:password@serverlocation:portnumber//DB name
'pg_dump' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have no spaces in the folder structure.

running the same exact command in cmd works fine (I am using a windows machine).

This is the command I am trying to run:

```
  const command = 'pg_dump --no-owner --file=d:\\Dev\\...\\..\\..\\...\\...bak postgres://Username:password@serverlocation:portnumber//DB name'
  let result = execSync(command)
```

Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Is `pg_dump` in your path?  Have you tried by putting a full path to `pg_dump`?

Comment: running the same exact command in cmd works fine (I am using a windows machine).

Comment: Well, you didn't answer either one of my questions.  Why is it so hard for people to just answer the questions we ask when we're trying to help you?  Perhaps there is no path set to it in the default cmd environment that `execSync()` uses.  You could determine if path was the issue by just trying the full path to `pg_dump`.  It's YOU who has to try things.  We can't do that.

Comment: yes, it is in the path.

Comment: Well, then try the full path so see if for some reason `execSync()` is not searching the path or doesn't have a path in its environment.  I may have read somewhere that you have to specifically start a `cmd` shell if you want it to search the path.

Comment: Resolved. Saw a similar question posted in which the resolution was to restart the machine. I did just that and it works. Sometimes you forget to try the most basic solutions. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by restarting the machine.